# Caching elements in templates

Tags: polymer

I have my main element using the flatiron-element to redirect my user:

```
....
<template if="{{route != null}}">
  <template if="{{route == 'home' || route == ''}}">
    <home-element structure="{{home}}"></home-element>
  </template>
  <template if="{{route == 'research'}}">
    <research-element structure="{{research}}"></research-element>
  </template>
  <template if="{{route == 'highlights'}}">
    <!-- <highlights-element></highlights-element> -->
  </template>
</template>
....
```

Each time I change {{route}}, the elements get recreated. Is there a good way to cache it so we do not have to reload it if it was previously loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is Polymer's template system instantiating each element as needed. When you cycle routes, it adds/removes the element from the DOM. The next time a round, the data-binding system stamps out a new instance of the element. This also means `created()` and `ready()` get called "again".

One option is to use `<polymer-ui-pages>` for this: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/polymer-ui-elements.html#polymer-ui-pages

Another is to show/hide elements as needed in CSS (instead of using conditional templates): http://jsbin.com/zeyoyisu/2/edit

Comment: OK thanks.

I want to avoid both options because, unless I mistake, it it gonna load all the pages, even though I might not need them.

Thanks